# Como utilizar variables de otra clase

Tags: java

Espero poder recibir ayuda, lo que sucede es que necesito utilizar variables de una clase en otra clase tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class piloto {

    public void PanelVenta(){

         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         panel.setLayout(null);
         UIManager.put("OptionPane.minimumSize", new Dimension(950, 600));

          for (int f = 0, x = 0, y = 0; f < listaPersonal.length; f++, x += 185) {
                if (f % 4 == 0) {
                    if (f != 0) {
                        y += 185;
                    }
                    x = 0;
                }
                listaPersonal[f].setBounds(x, y, 177, 153);
                panel.add(listaPersonal[f]);
            }
    }
```

La variable `listapersonal` la tengo en otra clase al momento de ponerla en este código me arroja el error de que `listapersonal` no se encuentra la verdad no se que puedo hacer espero me puedan orientar.

Comment: De que es tu array listaPersonal, podrías agregar la definición?

Comment: si claro mira es: JRadioButton[] listaPersonal;

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se realiza es modificar el método para que reciba el array `listaPersonal` :

```
public class piloto {

    public void PanelVenta(JRadioButton[] listaPersonal){
       ...
       ...
       ...
   }

}
```

de esta forma al instanciar la clase puedes enviar el array, ejemplo:

```
 piloto pil = new piloto();
 pil.PanelVenta(listaPersonal);
```